# How to fix laravel no command 'Redis::throttle'?

Tags: laravel

I just use doc example,but get the error 
`exception 'Predis\ClientException' with message 'Command 'THROTTLE' is not a registered Redis command.`

I havce search a lot about redis command,but nothing about `throttle`.

```
 public function handle()
    {
        // Allow only 2 emails every 1 second
        Redis::throttle('my-mailtrap')->allow(2)->every(1)->then(function () {

            $recipient = 'steven@example.com';
            Mail::to($recipient)->send(new OrderShipped($this->order));
            Log::info('Emailed order ' . $this->order->id);

        }, function () {
            // Could not obtain lock; this job will be re-queued
            return $this->release(2);
        });
    }
```

What should I do?Any help,Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`throttle` method is defined in `Illuminate/Redis/Connections/PredisConnection`.

The `Redis` facade allows for you to get the connection using

```php
Redis::connection()
    ->throttle('my-mailtrap')
    //...
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redis

Comment: Thanks,But I can't find `throttle` method in this file. Is that something wrong?
 https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/PredisConnection.php

Comment: I found it in `Illuminate/Redis/Connections/Connection.php`.But this version is 5.8 ,and my version is 5.4,and there is no method `throttle`,the problem now is clearly.Thanks a lot.Do you suggest me to upgrade now?

Comment: `PredisConnection` extends the abstract `Connection` class. Throttle isn't available for your version `5.4`. You may upgrade if you find that it isn't a lot of work to do.